# Git rebase --continue opens editor

Tags: git, git-rebase

After a rebase failed with a conflict, I could not continue the rebase using a Git GUI client. When performing

```
git rebase --continue
```

on command line (msysgit 1.7.4), it opened a text editor. After having closed it, Git continued. How can opening the editor be avoided?

Comment: What did the editor have in it? `rebase --continue` shouldn't spawn one, but other rebase operations do - and whenever Git starts an editor, it's because there really is something you might want to modify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress the editor for \`git rebase --continue\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489971/how-to-suppress-the-editor-for-git-rebase-continue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a rebase fails, you have to manually fix the file and then exec `git add filename` to  signal that everything is OK. At this point, `git rebase --continue` will continue the procedure without bothering you.

To change the default editor git uses issue: `git config --global core.editor new_editor`

> Commands such as commit and tag that lets you edit messages by launching an editor uses the value of this variable when it is set, and the environment variable GIT_EDITOR is not set. See git-var(1).

Comment: The conflicted file had been fixed and staged. Nevertheless, Git opened the text editor.

Comment: By *staged* you mean you executed `git add` on all files that have been changed?

Comment: It seems your `git rebase` is actually doing `git rebase -i`. Do you have aliases for git somewhere?

Comment: That's not the std behavior on Git for Linux. Maybe msysgit behaves different.

Comment: I don't use the command line, but my tool executed `git.exe rebase --preserve-merges <ID> <branch>`. The (now disappeared) tip for setting `GIT_EDITOR` to `cat` helped. :)

Comment: I'm using `git rebase -i` on Linux and it's more interactive than I want it, opening editor for commit messages with no good reason. Using `EDITOR=cat` fixes it.

Comment: @Pavel EDITOR=true works just as well without spilling the message file to the console.

Answer (score 1):

When a rebase incurs in conflicts, the user may need to make notable changes for resolving the them. Git assumes that the user wishes to modify the commit message, commenting on the conflict resolution.

This is documented in the paragraph [Commit Rewording](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_commit_rewording) of the `git rebase` man page.

A way to prevent the editor from being opened, and to confirm the original commit message is the following:

```
$ GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue
```