# How to suppress the editor for `git rebase --continue`?

Tags: git, macos, command-line, git-rewrite-history

I'm often rebasing interactive to make tiny changes in the history (for example removing a blank line, or editing one line). In most cases those changes are based on some peer review.

At first I do my change like that:

```bash
git rebase --interactive 83bbeb27fcb1b5e164318fa17c55b7a38e5d3c9d~
# replace "pick" by "edit" on the first line
# modify code
git commit --all --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

If there are merge conflicts in one of the following commits, I resolve them and do this:

```bash
git rebase --continue
# the commit message is shown, but does not have to be changed, so I just save and exit the editor
git rebase --continue
# the commit message is shown, but does not have to be changed, so I just save and exit the editor
git rebase --continue
# the commit message is shown, but does not have to be changed, so I just save and exit the editor
...
```

Is there anything like a `--no-edit` argument to `git rebase --continue` that avoids the editor (similar to `git commit`)?

Comment: Set your preferred editor to a does-nothing-and-succeeds command, such as `true`. Git will invoke it, it will do nothing and succeed, and Git will re-use the existing commit message.  Hence: `GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue`.

Comment: @torek Is there a way to apply the change of the editor to only *one* git command? I tried `;` (like that: `GIT_EDITOR=true;git rebase --continue`), but that did not work. (I'm using a mac, btw)

Comment: That (environment setting via shell `VAR=val cmd...`) *does* affect just the one command, plus anything it runs itself. To affect multiple commands you must set the variable and "export" it, which in most shells is `export VAR=value; command1; command2; ...`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First approach, through Git configuration:

```
git -c core.editor=true rebase --continue
```

Or, with environment variables:

```
GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue
```

This will override the editor that `git` uses for message confirmation. `true` command simply ends with zero exit code. It makes `git` continue `rebase` as if user closed interactive editor.

On Windows, you would need to [use `CMD /V /C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309)

```bash
cmd /V /C "set "GIT_EDITOR=true" && git rebase --continue
```

In both OS, you can use aliases

```bash
# Linux
alias grc='GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase --continue'

# Windows
doskey grc=cmd /V /C "set "GIT_EDITOR=true" && git rebase --continue"
```

Then a simple `grc` will be enough to continue the rebase *without* the editor popping up.

---

[David Gardiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25702/david-gardiner) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489971/how-to-suppress-the-editor-for-git-rebase-continue/45783848#comment130045522_45783848):

> In PowerShell, use:
>
> ```bash
> $env:GIT_EDITOR = "true -and git rebase --continue"
> ```
>
> then tidy up with
>
> ```bash
>  $env:GIT_EDITOR = ""
> ```

---

To set that globally (without alias), maybe consider [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350016/6309):

> specifying the core.commentChar detected from the .git/rebase-merge/message (here @):
>
> ```bash
> git --global core.commentChar @
> ```

There is also [`GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970726/6309), but you cannot always leave it at that value, because that would break all the rebase operation where you *want* an editor.

That is why having an alias remains the most flexible and accurate approach, rather than relying on a global setting which might break other rebase editor use cases.

Comment: Setting env var like `var=val` works only for shell. In order to make ti work for all processes that will be started after that you need to call `export var`. Doing everything as single command can be `export var=val`. But it would be bad idea to override `GIT_EDITOR` for all other invocations of `git`. So the final recommendation (`var=val command`) is the best one because it has no negative side effect.

Comment: @VictorYarema Thank you for the comment and the edit: this answer is clearer now, thanks to you.

Comment: Is there a way to config it globally? I know it's possible because this is how it worked on my old computer..

Comment: @MoshFeu Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350016/6309

Comment: Thanks! I will check it

Comment: In PowerShell, use:
`$env:GIT_EDITOR = "true -and git rebase --continue"`, 
then tidy up with `$env:GIT_EDITOR = ""`

Comment: @DavidGardiner Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 19):

The trick of using `true` as an editor can also be accomplished with a git alias like this:

```
[alias]
    continue = "-c core.editor=true rebase --continue"
```

Then you use `git continue` instead of `git rebase --continue`.